# VirtualBox: Making a Keylogger file from Kali VM after exploiting Metasploitable (Bridged Adapter)

Tags: exploit, virtualbox

I am fairly new to Kali Linux and Metasploitable and I am trying to set a keylogger for when I gain root access to Metasploitable. I have gained root access by using the  `use exploit/unix/irc/unreal_ircd_3281_backdoor` (I followed everything from [here](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/unix/irc/unreal_ircd_3281_backdoor/)) and have successfully penetrated Metasploitable. However, I am using a Bridged Adapter network to make this work and I would like to use a [keylogger](https://github.com/gsingh93/simple-key-logger.git) that is already downloaded into Kali Linux rather than use `wget` as I have no access to the internet from Kali Linux.

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZhGNd4IMHk&ab_channel=MeetZalavadia) and he has made the code into a DropBox link, however, I would like to use the downloaded file that is already on Kali Linux.

If there is an easier way to do a keylogger from Kali VM after exploiting Metasploit, please do not be afraid to suggest it.

Comment: This does not look like a security question for me. It is more about network setup and how to share a file between different VM. It does not actually matter if the file should be retrieved from inside an exploit or outside - but that it is retrieved from a different VM.